# Why am I getting this instead of a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This is my code that works so far, as it adds a point and saves it as it should. However, when I try to make the bot say it says "[object Object]haha". How can I fix this? Code:

```js
var davebal = 0;
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
 if (msg.content == '-readdata') {
  let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(msg.author + '.json');
  let student = JSON.parse(rawdata);
  msg.reply(student + 'haha');
  console.log(student);
 }

 if (msg.content == '-add') {
  if (msg.author == '349463140229971989') {
   davebal += 1;
   msg.reply('Az új számlád = ' + davebal);
  }
 }

 if (msg.content == '-savedata') {
  let balance = {
   balancefor: davebal,
  };

  let data = JSON.stringify(balance);
  fs.writeFileSync(msg.author + '.json', data);
 }
});
```

Comment: what is `typeof student`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: typeof student is of type object that's why you are getting [object Object] in nested object

Comment: I am not sure, I just started trying to understand saving stuff in .json and i am new to javascript too.

Comment: what is inside the file msg.author + '.json' ?

Comment: You can use typeof to find the variable type of student. Suspect it is not string, but js object. That’s why it is is showing [object] in output.

Comment: Yes, I think that's why but how can I make it a string?

Comment: The contents of the file is : {"balancefor":3}, that's what is supposed to be inside of it

Comment: you cannot add object with string

Comment: okay, I got it. I just did `JSON.stringify(student)` and it worked.

Comment: you can directly pass rawdata you don't need to parse and then stringify again

Comment: I did not know that

Comment: Is it possible to remove the brackets and the "s and the : from it?

Comment: I know i can do it like this but IDK how to do each thing I want to be replaced at the same time `rawdata.split(new RegExp('wordtochange', 'i')).join('changetothis')`

Comment: you can use `replace` for that

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because student is a object, I would recommend getting a property from the object, such as `student.name` or something instead of just `student`.